# push, pop, and basic heap

Tags: c++

Simple question when I mess around with 
[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) and change the  pop_heap

```
std::vector<int> v { 60 , 20 , 50 , 10 , 5 , 30 , 45 };

std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

std::cout << "v: ";
for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); // moves the largest to the end


The result is:
v: 60 20 50 10 5 30 45 
after pop_heap: 50 20 45 10 5 30 60
```

CPP Reference tells me that

**std::pop_heap**-Swaps the value in the position first and the value in the position last-1 and makes the subrange [first, last-1) into a max heap. This has the effect of removing the first (largest) element from the heap defined by the range [first, last).

I know I am missing something because if I read the would the first and last be swapped. I know that after everything is said and done the pop_heap will eliminate 60 but how is it that the order ends up the way it does. I think my not understand lies with last-1 but I cannot be sure

Comment: like it said, swap `first` with `last - 1` then do something like `std::make_heap(first, last - 1)`

Comment: What does last-1 mean? this is where my hangup is

Comment: See this example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39cf3879c64bbbe5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `std::pop_heap` you specify `first` as `v.begin()`, which returns an iterator pointing to the first element and `last` as `v.end()` which, according to  [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/) "Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container.". That means that `last-1` actually is the last element in your vector. So the elements that are swapped are the first (`60`) and the last (`45`). Afterwards the subrange [`first`, `last-1`), meaning everything BUT the last element (which is now `60`) is made into a `heap` again, meaning that the first element is the largest (`50`).

So for the order it is garantied that the first element in your vector is `50` and the last one is `60`. As for the rest, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) states in the notes:

> A max heap is a range of elements [f,l) that has the following properties:
>
> - *f is the largest element in the range
> - a new element can be added using std::push_heap()
> - the first element can be removed using std::pop_heap()
>
> The actual arrangement of the elements is implementation defined.

So the rest is just aranged in a way to that is convenient for implementation of the methods.

Comment: How would this be different that push_heap? From the examples  it looks the same.

Comment: @CSStudentzzz No `push_heap` does the opposit. It takes the `last-1`'th value and puts it into the heap that used to be [`first`,`last-1`). If you were to call that function after `pop_heap` it would make `60` the first element again.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap , it doesn't work like or if it does I am missing something. If we didn't add the 6 like the link does the 9 go back to the end?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your problem. After `make_heap`, `v = {9, 5, 4, 1, 1, 3}`. Then a `6` is added and `push_heap` adds it to the heap but since `9` is still the biggest number, it remains in front and for the rest of the numbers "The actual arrangement of the elements is implementation defined." still holds. In a `heap` the biggest number is the front element.

Answer (score 0):

Like it said, swap `first` with `last - 1` then do something like `std::make_heap(first, last - 1)`

Note: `first` and `last` are 2 parameters of `std::pop_heap` which is your `v.begin()` and `v.end()` respectively. It means that it will swap `v.begin()` and `v.end() - 1` in your example.

See this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39cf3879c64bbbe5)

Comment: that's fine but your example just proves cpprefence is wrong for my set of numbers, why is that?